# Can I enable the desktop to create files, folders and shortcuts? In loki

Tags: release-loki, desktop

I am testing Elementary OS loki, I find it very interesting, but note that I can not create any file on the desktop which seems to me to be wasting a lot of resources in terms of organization, well I use the desktop a lot, that's why I'd like to know if There is some configuration that I must change to be able to enable the desktop, I would greatly appreciate your support. regards

Comment: @lemonsile, It is not duplicated because that question you mentioned was published 1 year ago and Elementary OS loki, released a few months ago, must be different versions.

Comment: It is a long-term design decision which does not change with each release.

Comment: I understand, I will review and if I see that if it is duplicated then I delete it, but it could also help those who have the same doubt

Comment: You don't need to delete it. It's only that with the possible duplicate tagged you can find the information still relevant at the other question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a video that explains how to do it, I share it in case someone has the same doubt. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qa3w2bDCM0A